# chrome extension do foreach after redirecting to new url

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

hello everyone i am developing an extension that takes a list of numbers then send a message to them using api call but the api call has a button that should be clicked manually to send the message thats why i am using chrome extensions to do the job

however to send a message to the entire list, i have to do foreach, and also put each number in the url, for it takes the number and the message as parameters from the request

here is my code

sender.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click' , onclick , false)
    function onclick(){
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true , active:true}, 
            function(tabs){
                var numbers = [];
                var message_body ='';
                numbers = document.getElementById("number-list").value;
                var numbers_list = numbers.split("\n");
                message_body = document.getElementById('message-body').value;
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {splited_numbers : numbers_list , message : message_body});
            }
          )
    }
},false)
```

content.js

```
    //this will click the button
    setTimeout(
      () => {
       document.querySelector('span[data-icon="send"]').click()
      },
      15 * 1000
    );

//this will do the redirect 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
      setTimeout(
      () =>{
        request.splited_numbers.forEach(element => {
        window.location.replace(`url/phone=${element}&text=${request.message}`)
      });
      },
      16 * 1000
      )
    })
```

the thing is i want to redirect the page to this url click the button then re do it untill the last number of the list but when i put two numbers it sends only for the last number in the list 
and foreach doesn't work for some reason 
Note Console doesn't show any errors

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you update `location` the old page and its script are destroyed (inculding your content scripts) and a new page is loaded. You'll need to move that part into the background script so it'll send a message to the page on timer or directly update the url via chrome.tabs.update.

Comment: well i replaced it with  chrome.tabs.update(tabs.id , {url instead of location replace but didn't work it sent only for the last number in my list and ignored everyone above it